# What bird is singing at almost 3 AM in Hong Kong? (recording included)

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I live in Hong Kong and there’s a bird around my street that sings around 3 AM, when there isn’t the slightest bit of twilight.

I have recorded its song here: https://youtube.com/shorts/0dBNvPAgLmU?feature=share

Can somebody identify it?

Comment: +1 for providing *an actual recording!* Can you describe a bit more about the song? For example, is it several seconds long and repeats, or goes on and on for up to a minute in a somewhat rambling, non-repeating way (which describes what I often hear between 3 and 5 AM in Taiwan)